# Printing out garbage when going through a textfile and looking for how many instances of a word appears

Tags: c

I need to go through a text file and count how many times a word appears. I put the user input (word) into char array called word and am using strstr to see if that instance of word appears in the text file. But the problem I am having right now is that in my last final print statement, it is printing out garbage. It should print, the word "awful" appeared 28 times, but I think it is not printing the string at all and it is printing out some random value for the number of times the word appears in the text file. Pointers confuse the hell out of me, and I thought it was printing out the address, but it keeps printing out the same number constantly. I tried putting & signs on my word and num but it doesn't seem to fix anything.

Here is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getWordStats(char *word, FILE *f, int *sum, int *num);

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{  
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    char word[15];

    int *num;
    int *sum;

    printf("Enter word: ");

    scanf("%s", word);

    getWordStats(word, f, sum, num);
}

void getWordStats(char *word, FILE *f, int *sum, int *num)
{   
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        fscanf(f, "%s", word);
        if(strstr((char*)f, word))
        num++;
    }

      printf("%s appeared %d times\n", word ,num);
}
```

Comment: At the start ur num pointer is not initialized so write *num= 0 Try printf (blabla, *num) you are printing the adress the pointer is pointing to not its value also insted of num++ write (*num) ++

Comment: What does `(char*)f` mean?! A file is not a string.

Comment: @Bo Persson he has so many errors, does the code even compile?

Comment: @Rostin yeah it compiles

Comment: @Anonymous look at the answer provided by hunteke also fix the fscanf ( read another char* from it) and replace the f in strstr () with the new char*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the pointer `*num`.  You have passed a *reference* to num to `getWordStats`.  When you increment `num`, you are incrementing where the pointer points, not the value, which is stored at `*num`.  Increment the value, not the pointer, by changing `num++` to `(*num)++;`.

Then, when printing, again, print the *value*, not the place in memory:

```
printf("%s appeared %d times\n", word , *num);
```

Additionally, you never initialized *num to 0, so it could be any random value.

```
int main ( ... ) {
    ...
    int *num = 0;
    ...
 }
```

EDIT: thanks to @Rostin for the below.

I'm also not sure what you're doing with `strstr`, currently.  `strstr` searches through a character array (`*char`), but you have passed it a pointer to a file (`*FILE`) while telling the compiler "Trust me, this is *really* a character string."  You will need to pull in data from the file, and pass **that** to `strstr`.

Comment: Dont forget about his printf and his strstr ()

Comment: Thanks i will try this


EDIT: Should I try strcmp then?

Comment: @Anonymous no, `strstr` is what you want, I think.  The part you are missing is how to get the _content_ of the file.  You've opened the file.  Now what?  Having an open file handle is quite different from searching through strings.  Remember, this is C, where **nothing** is provided for you.  You either need to find a library that does exactly what you want, or you need to tell C what you want it to do.  Not doing your work for you, I might suggest googling the phrase 'c search file for string', or similar.